# Unable to publish Azure website

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2013

When we are trying to publish site to Azure from VS 2013 we are getting

C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(4270,5): Warning : Retrying the sync because a socket error (10054) occurred.

Retrying operation 'Serialization' on object sitemanifest (sourcePath). Attempt 1 of 10.

can you guys have any idea why I am getting this error? Previously it was working.